# HDFS + lsof + how to find the files that are currently being used for each HDFS folder

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, lsof

We are trying to find the currently being used of opened files on each folder in HDFS.

So we try the following

```
hadoop fs -lsof /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1586272450810_3249
```

But this doesn’t work.

We can do the following in order to calculate the files under the folder as

```
hdfs fsck /user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1586272450810_3249 -files -blocks -locations -openforwrite | grep "Total files"

Total files:   29
```

But this is only the total files under the folder and not the opened files that are used for HDFS folder - `/user/hdfs/.sparkStaging/application_1586272450810_3249`

Any idea how to use the `lsof` in order to get the real open files for HDFS folder ?

NOTE:
*The reason for this test is to know what are the folders in HDFS that have the most files that are in use, and maybe this way we can find the reason which processes running on HDFS take the most memory resources*.

Comment: Hadoop shell command doesn't have `lsof` option, so why try it? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html

Comment: You can not really use the lsof on the hdfs filesystem. hdfs does not support the action. This makes sense because lsof is not anything with respect to filesystem but rather it fetches information on process level.
To achieve your goal you might have to look the through the jobs that are running to read from hdfs as well as schedule of those jobs.

If you can elaborate on your goal, may be i can think of something.